# Can only search social network messages in the Dash after 13.10 upgrade

Tags: 13.10, unity-dash

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10, when I click on the Dash icon I can only see social media search results. I can't type in applications or see a list of applications to launch.

[image]

Comment: Please provide snapshot to make it more clear what you trying to say

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aMQcE.png I don't have enough rep for a pic yet

Comment: click on filter results and then select applications and see what happens

Comment: There is no applications option to select. Filter results tab is open if I click the tab again based on the image it closes it.

Answer (score 1):

Running the following command solved the problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-scope-home
```